# Is there any complete grammatical description of German in a modern theory of syntax?

Tags: reference-request

The Duden offers the most complete grammar of German currently. However, has anyone tried to use a modern framework like Head-Driven Phrase Structure Grammar or the Minimalist Program to as comprehensively describe the German language?

Comment: There is a stackexchange site for linguistics as well.

Answer (score 3):

The only work I know of covering this rather particular topic is:

> Heike Schulz; Die Syntax der Konstruktion: Eine Phrasenstrukturgrammatik des Deutschen mit einem erweiterten Valenzbegriff

It is from 1998, issued by Peter Lang GmbH, Internationaler Verlag der Wissenschaften

ISBN-13: 9783631333006
ISBN-10: 3631333005